# Can VMWare support USB DVD Writer?

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, vmware

If I install Windows7 as guest OS in VMWare Workstation or other VMWare versions, can I use USB DVD writer in Windows? Are there any compatibility problems? I don't have such a writer now, but I'd like to evaluate it before I use it.

Comment: I have not any comapatiblity problems with USB but I haven't USB DVD writer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've never tried it with a USB DVD writer, but VMWare automatically detects both my internal disk drive and other USB devices such as thumb drives and xbox controllers. I see no reason why it wouldn't work with a DVD writer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect it to work fine.  VMware lets the guest OS talk directly to the USB device, so it should be the same as using it from outside a VM.

You can use SATA burners from within a virtual machine as well.  I've burned discs, erased discs, and even upgraded my drive's firmware from within a VM.  In prior versions of VMware and Windows, I had to configure the virtual drive as SCSI (though the actual hardware is SATA), and had to "connect" it to the VM early in the boot process, before the guest OS loaded any drivers.  But with Workstation 8 and Windows 7, those steps don't seem to be necessary.